# Is it still possible to install Minecraft 15w14a (love and hugs update)?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Year ago Mojang posted April fools joke snapshot 15w14a or just simply  The Love and Hugs Update. I dont know if its possible to play it now but if its possible can somebody help me ? P.s If somebody know then please post me a link to download and write tutorial ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While this game version is no longer listed in the launcher, you can still download the game files directly from the Mojang servers, provided you know where they are stored. Luckily, the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/15w14a) has you covered: The links to the [client .jar](https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/15w14a/15w14a.jar) and [.json](https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/15w14a/15w14a.json), as well as the [server .jar](https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/15w14a/minecraft_server.15w14a.jar) are listed in the info-box. These are the official download links to the files hosted by Mojang themselves.

To install a version not listed in the launcher, follow these steps:

1. Go to your `.minecraft` directory (e.g. `%appdata%\.minecraft` in Windows) and open the folder called `versions`.
2. Create a new folder here, and name it "15w14a".
3. Place the two client files (`15w14a.jar` and `15w14a.json`) inside this folder.
4. Open your Minecraft launcher and click on <kbd>Edit Profile</kbd>
5. Under "Version Selection", check the box labeled "Enable experimental development versions ("snapshots")".
6. Select "15w14a" from the version dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Picture from Launcher]

It isn't available on the Launcher so you'll have to install it manually.

[First, download this](https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/15w14a/15w14a.jar) (rename to `15w14a.jar` if it is `15w14a.zip`) and [this](https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/15w14a/15w14a.json).

Go to `%appdata%\.minecraft\versions\` on Windows, `~/.minecraft/versions/` on Linux and `~/Library/Application Support/minecraft/versions/` on Mac, and create a folder called `15w14a`, and put those 2 files in, you'll now be able to switch to that version on launcher.

Comment: @aytimothy edited.